# f is monotonically decreasing convex invertible function

Tags: calculus, functions

> let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a monotonically decreasing convex invertible function. is $f^{-1}$ convex as well? is the condition that f is monotone is essential?

I tried to take some examples and find a contradiction, but none of my examples is fit. I think that the statement is true and that the condition is essenetial (we can take $x^2$ as an example for a contradiction).

Now, after understanding that the statement is probably true, I tried to go from definitions of convexity and monotony, but got nowhere.

How may someone prove the statement?

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement is true. If you assume strict monotonicity the proof can be found [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Convex_Strictly_Monotone_Function). The condition of monotonicity is essential as your example with $x^2$ shows.

For the non-strict case you can found a proof [here](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/20/tm1112.pdf) in Proposition 2(2). According to the author if $f$ is two times differentiable there is an easier proof which he gives in Proposition 1. (2)

Comment: e^x is not monotonically decreasing...

Comment: @Galc127 true, sorry. I will delete it

Comment: @Galc127 The proof is for strict monotonic. That is not what you want, is it?

Comment: No, the function is defined to be monotonically decreasing, convex and invertible.

Comment: @Galc127 I think that is exactly what you want in Proposition 2(2). You have additionally that $f^-1$ is also decreasing

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot.